# Issue trying to use the IIF function in SSRS 2014

Tags: reporting-services

I am new to SSR but I am trying to use one textbox value depending on if the time of day < a specific time value and another textbox value if time of day > a specific time value by using the IIF function in my code. Any help/direction would be appreciated.  Thanks.

The error I get when saving the changes:

> The Value expression for the textrun
>   ‘txtHeader.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]’ contains a colon or a line
>   terminator.  Colons and line terminators are not valid in expressions.

Here is my code:

```
=IIF((FormatDateTime(Now(),HH:mm)) < "1617", "Early Childhood Registration Report" & VbCrLf & "Total Number of No Enrollment School" 
    & VbCrLf & "(includes student records updated thru: " & DateAdd("d", -1, Today()) & " at 4:17 pm)"), 
    IIF((FomatDateTime(Now(),HH:mm)) > "1617", "Early Childhood Registration Report" & VbCrLf & "Total Number of No Enrollment School" & VbCrLf & "(includes student records updated thru: " & DateAdd("d", 1, Today()) & " at 4:17 pm)")
```

Comment: Thanks R.  I appreciate the formatting help.

Answer (score 2):

FormatDateTime(Now(),HH:mm) needs to be FormatDateTime(Now(),"HH:mm")

Comment: Thanks Edward.  That got it.  I appreciate your help.